# Detect client is connected to which port

Tags: python, twisted

I have the following code and I want to detect in which port client is connected to factory. How can I achieve that?

```
from twisted.internet import reactor
conn = txredisapi.lazyRedisConnectionPool(reconnect = True)
factory = STSFactory(conn)
factory.clients = []

print "Server started"
reactor.listenTCP(11000,factory)
reactor.listenTCP(11001,factory)
reactor.listenTCP(11002,factory)
reactor.run()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two addresses of a TCP connection, the client address and the server address, can be retrieved using the transport's `getHost` and `getPeer` methods.  The "host" address is the address of the local side of the connection.  The "peer" address is the address of the other side of the connection.  On a server, the host address is also the address of the port which accepted the connection.

[You can read about transport methods in the Twisted API documentation.](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.internet.interfaces.ITransport.html)

For example:

```
class SomeProtocol(Protocol):
    def connectionMade(self):
        print 'Connection made to', self.transport.getHost(),
        print 'from', self.transport.getPeer()
```